# How do I view results as text, as opposed to worksheet view in Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I can only get results from running SQL queries in the worksheet view. I want to view it as text. I know this was possible in past releases.

Answer (score 14):

I think you want the "Run Script" (F5) command rather than the "Run Statement" (Ctrl-Enter) command.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a workaround

**To get a text copy of the Worksheet View including Headers.**

1. Click on any cell in the worksheet view.
2. Press <kbd>CTRL-A</kbd> then <kbd>CTRL-SHIFT-C</kbd>

The contents of the worksheet view are now presents as text and can be pasted elsewhere.